# angular resource 400 bad request

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-400

Hi i have some trouble with angular resources, I tried an url in post method however i get an 400 error bad request.

It's maybe my mistake but i tried in CURL

```
curl -d widget_type=creativity -d settings='{"idea":"local:Idea/2"}' url/data/Discussion/1/widgets
```

I receive the right response from the server but when i try with angular it does not work.

This is my directive

```
creativityServices.factory('configService', ['$resource',function($resource){
return $resource('url/data/Discussion/:discussionId/widgets')
}]);
```

And in my controller

```
var config = new configService();
    config.widget_type ='creativity';
    config.settings ={"idea":"local:Idea/2"};
    config.$save({discussionId:1}, function(data){

        console.log('success', data);

    }, function(data){

        console.log('error', data);

    });
```

Thank for your help